# MAC Address regex validation for comma separated, colon or dash delimited values

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, mac-address

I am using the following Regex for validating MAC Addresses:

```
pattern("^([a-fA-f0-9]){12}(,\s*([a-fA-f0-9]){12})*$")
```

and it works fine for the following input:

```
12aeabc11bba,662baea1abc2
```

I'd like to improve it to support the following MAC Address styles:

```
12-ae-ab-c1-1b-ba,66-2b-ae-a1-ab-c2
12ae-abc1-1bba,662b-aea1-abc2
12:ae:ab:c1:1b:ba,66:2b:ae:a1:ab:c2
12ae:abc1:1bba,662b:aea1:abc2
12aeabc11bba,662baea1abc2
```

It is not required for the Regex to support the following MAC Address styles, however it is OK if the Regex permits these:

```
12:ae:ab:c1:1b:ba,66-2b-ae-a1-ab-c2
2134:12:12:1234,ae-12-ae-42-62-ae
ae12-bc33-a122,fe12:ae12:ab54
ae12:bc33-a122
```

I am using `Angular5`, and this validation is passed to the `FormBuilder` validation, so I don't think I can put in multiple patterns.

```
this.requestForm = this.fb.group({
    macAddresses: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^([a-fA-f0-9]){12}(,\s*([a-fA-f0-9]){12})*$")]]
});
```

Can anyone help solve the problem?

Whoever answers this question with the cleanest solution will get a bounty award of 100 rep

Comment: Should it work with `12:ae:ab:c1:1b:ba,66-2b-ae-a1-ab-c2`? Should it match `12-ae-abc1:1b-ba`?

Comment: [`\b[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[:-]?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Q5P1De/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[:-]?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}(?:,[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[:-]?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5})*$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5P1De/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}` - matches 2 occurrences of either a digit or a letter in the range `a-f` or `A-F`
- `(?:[:-]?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}` - matches 0 or 1 occurrence of either a `:` or `-`. followed by 5 occurrences of either a digit or a letter in the range `a-f` or `A-F`
- `(?:,[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[:-]?[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5})*` - Matches a `,` followed by the MAC address. The `*` at the end indicates 0+ occurrences of `,` followed by MAC address.
- `$` - asserts the end of the line.